# ng-click function called from button , wont recognize input entered by user

Tags: angularjs

im new to angular and trying to pass value to function after user changed it. the input field and the button are both inside `<td>`. problem is function gets the value initialized the table and not recognizing the value entered by user .
this is the `<td>`:

```
   <td class="cronFormat">
       <input type="text"  ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index"  value="{{letter}}"/>
       <button  class="save" ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format,oldCron)">save</button>
   </td>
```

cron_format always equals to the value initialized the cell. how can i make `saveCron()` get the value user entered?
thanks for helping

**UPDATE**
so i tried to add `ng-model="l"` and use it in the function like this:
`$scope.l` but it is undefined...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model in your scope and bind your inputs to the model, then make saveCron save the model.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<td class="cronFormat">
   <input type="text"  ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index" ng-model="letter"/>
   <button  class="save" ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format,oldCron)">save</button>
</td>
```

then, in `saveCron()`, you could access user's modified `letter` value in `$scope.letter`...

Comment: hi thanks for helping...i tried to do this and...you can look at the update in my post